# Solving ODE using complex numbers

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I was studying the Zeeman effect when we arrived at the system of ODE:
$$x''+\omega ^2 x + eBy'/m=0$$
$$y''+\omega ^2 y - eBx'/m=0$$
And the solution was given as:
$$u(t)=x(t)+iy(t)=u_0 \cdot Exp(-it(\omega-eB/2m))$$
$$v(t)=x(t)-iy(t)=v_0 \cdot Exp(-it(\omega+eB/2m))$$
The solution does indeed check out, but I haven't understood how we get to the solution using that substitution. It was said that "the solution is straightforward with that substitution", but after some algebra I get to:
$$u''+\omega ^2 u + ieBv'/m=0$$
$$v''+\omega ^2 v - ieBu'/m=0$$
which are pretty much the equations of the initial ODE, so I don't see how to solve the system "straightforwardly" using that substitution.

Also, trying to find back $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ we can use:
$$x(t)= Re(u(t))= Re(u_0)\cdot cos(t(\omega-eB/2m))+Im(u_0)\cdot sin(t(\omega-eB/2m))$$ or
$$x(t)= Re(v(t))= Re(v_0)\cdot cos(t(\omega+eB/2m))+Im(v_0)\cdot sin(t(\omega+eB/2m))$$
And those things are oscillating at different frequencies, so I'm starting to get really confused here.

Comment: Not sure if this fixes it, but remember $Re(z_1z_2) =Re(z_1)Re(z_2) - Im(z_1)Im(z_2) \ne Re(z_1)Re(z_2)$.

Comment: Good point, I'm going to edit the question.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $k=eB/m$. We have the coupled ODE \begin{align}x''+\omega^2x+ky'&=0\tag1\\y''+\omega^2y-kx'&=0\tag2.\end{align} Note $(1)+i\times(2)$ gives $(x+iy)''+\omega^2(x+iy)-ik(x+iy)'=0$ so we have the one-variable ODE $$u''-iku'+\omega^2u=0.$$ This can readily be solved for $u(x,y)$ and the solutions $x(t)$, $y(t)$ can be determined by equating real and imaginary parts.

---

The full solution is $$u(t)=e^{ikt/2}\left(Ce^{-it\sqrt{(k/2)^2+\omega^2}}+De^{it\sqrt{(k/2)^2+\omega^2}}\right)$$ so $$x(t)=C\cos\left(t(K-\sqrt{K^2+\omega^2})\right)+D\cos\left(t(K+\sqrt{K^2+\omega^2})\right)$$ where $K=k/2=eB/2m$ and similarly for $y(t)$.

Comment: Ok, so if you take $(1)-i \cdot (2)$ you get an equivalent equation for what I've called v and indeed it turns out that the real part is the same and the imaginary part is the same with a minus sign, so everything checks out in your solution. So I guess you can choose C and D opportunely to get the u(t) that I've written. Does that mean that I can't compare the x(t) I got from u and the one I got from v because they come from particular (different) choices of the free parameters?

Comment: No, the $x(t)$s from $u$ and $v$ are exactly the same. Note $v(t)$ is the same as $u(t)$ if you let $Y(t)=-y(t)$; $x(t)$ remains unchanged.